# App crashing in specific android versions

Tags: android, crash

I have an app which is crashing in specific android api levels like 4.2 and 4.4. 
My minimum level is 16 and target sdk is 24.

This is the error logcat:

```
10-14 22:37:49.600 4519-4519/com.encodezero.projectred E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.android.tools.fd.runtime.AppInfo
                                                                             at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication.<init>(BootstrapApplication.java:119)
                                                                             at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
                                                                             at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:982)
                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:967)
                                                                             at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:496)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4181)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:136)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1261)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4802)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:813)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:580)
                                                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

How to remove such kind on error ?

Answer (score 0):

You may be hitting the method limit error.  See [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html) for more info on configuring for multidex.